# How do I boot into developer mode on Lenovo 500e Chromebook 2nd Gen when device management blocks it

Tags: google-chrome-os

I have a Lenovo Chromebook 500e 2nd gen which I need to boot into developer mode, but a device management blocks it. I bought the chromebook secondhand but it has a device management on it which blocks me from going into developer mode.

I tried recovering it(powerwasing was disabled) using the chromebook recovery utility but am always forced back into enterprise enrollment

I would appreciate any help given. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to bypass it, that's the entire idea. [You could on the early ones but not any more.] The company/school who locked it are the only ones who can release it.

If you can't contact them to unenroll it, or send it back to the seller for a refund, you own a brick I'm afraid.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you very much